# Golang convert stringified list to slice

Tags: go

I have a workflow where a list is created and sent to an SQS queue (and as such must be converted to a string) where it is later picked up by a Go function. I need to parse the following stringified list:

```
"['bucket___file1.csv___groupFile.csv___custom', 'bucket___file2.csv___groupFile.csv___modeler']"
```

into a slice of strings like this:

```
[]string{'bucket___file1.csv___groupFile.csv___custom', 'bucket___file2.csv___groupFile.csv___modeler'}
```

so I can access and parse them by index. How would I do this?

Comment: It looks like JSON or JSON-alike. Try using Go's JSON decoder.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

Comment: Will this work even though it's not a JSON at all? It's a straight up string of a python list

Comment: It's definitely not JSON. JSON uses double quotes for strings. You'd likely have to build your own parser, but if you're only dealing with lists of strings, that should be pretty easy to do.

Comment: The list will always be in this format. I could just split it on the commas and then replace the `[` and `]` with nothing, but that feels kinda hacky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your string to json and use json decoder to get an array of string

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    inputString := "['bucket___file1.csv___groupFile.csv___custom', 'bucket___file2.csv___groupFile.csv___modeler']"
    // convert string to json string

    jsonString := strings.ReplaceAll(inputString, "'", "\"")

    var expectedStringArray []string
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &expectedStringArray)

    fmt.Println(expectedStringArray)
}
```

This should solve your issue

Please note that the above solution will fail when you have `'` in one of your array string.

For a solid solution You can push proper JSON to the queue and you can skip the conversion part in the solution I have provided above.